# how can I have CollectionView of CollectionView in marionette.js?

Tags: javascript, marionette, backbone-relational

I have a use case where I want to have a collection of collectionViews (or composite views) rendered. What is the best way to do this using marionette.js?

My model structure is as follows-

```
A 
|
|-- Collection<B>
               |
               |--Collection<C>
```

I want to render as follows -

```
A1
|
|--B1
|  |
|  C1
|  |
|  C2
|  |
|  C3
|
|--B2
   |
   C4
   |
   C5
   |
   C6
```

What is the best way to do this?
I don't want it to be like this

```
A1
|
|--B1
|  |
|  |--C1
|  |
|  |--C2
|  |
|  |--C3
|
|--B2
   |
   |--C4
   |
   |--C5
   |
   |--C6
```

Comment: I have a fairly complex structure with different views for each level i.e. different views for A,B and C. I have many events to handle, morever, I want a sort functionality (on clicking sort button, the DOM should be sorted). how can I do this?

Comment: Any examples of source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you could achieve this by creating a collection view that can deiced if the child it is trying to display has a collection or if is just a model. So for this example i have set up a model which has a name and an optional collection, if the collection is used then it will contain  a collection of models which in turn can have an optional collection.

Then define a collection view, the collection view will check if the child has a collection and it if does will use the collection view as the child.

```
//collection view that can choose to display another collection view or a model
myApp.Views.View1 = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: "ul",
    //overridden getChildView to return either another collection view or an item view
    getChildView: function (child) {
        if (child.get("collection")) {
            return myApp.Views.View1;
        }
        return myApp.Views.ItemView;
    },

    //set either the collection or the model depending which view we are using
    childViewOptions: function (model, index) {
        if (model.get("collection")) {
            return {
                collection: model.get("collection"),
            }
        } else {
            return {
                model: model
            }
        }
    }
});
```

if it doesn't then it will just use an item view to display the model

```
//item view to display final model
myApp.Views.ItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    template: _.template('<%= name %>'),
})
```

here it is running - http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/r5ogoL5h/

If you wanted to display the names of the models being render above the collection then you can use a composite view, this also allows us more control on hooking into the view to display the collection

```
//collection view that can choose to display another collection view or a model
myApp.Views.View1 = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    tagName: "ul",
    template: _.template('<li><%= name %></li><li><ul class="collectionHook"></ul></li>'),
    childViewContainer: ".collectionHook",
    //overridden getChildView to return either another collection view or an item view
    getChildView: function (child) {
        if (child.get("collection")) {
            return myApp.Views.View1;
        }
        return myApp.Views.ItemView;
    },

    //set either the collection or the model depending which view we are using
    childViewOptions: function (model, index) {
        if (model.get("collection")) {
            return {
                model: model,
                collection: model.get("collection"),
            }
        } else {
            return {
                model: model
            }
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/kx9kuup0/

only issue is the html isn't 100% valid as you end up with a double `<ul>` when you display a composite view inside a composite view but with some tweaking that could be fixed, it still renders correctly though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the jsfiddle example shows just what I didn't want. I want the elements "collection 1 elent 1","collection 1 elent 2" just on the level of "root collection 1" and not under "root collection 1". I have got pointers though, thanks!

Comment: @pratik That just becomes a matter of styling, I have updated the second fiddle to include some css to allow for the what i think you wanted. The other option is to not use lists and use just divs with specific classes that can again be styled